# Adding two time columns together in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

I have the following data:

```
 time_begin  DRTN_IN_SCND
 16:22:16           439
 16:29:37            53
 16:30:33            85
```

I would like to make a new column that adds time_begin and DRTN_IN_SCND (the duration in seconds) to create a new time.

I have tried:

```
df['new_time'] = df['time_begin'].apply(lambda x: (dt.datetime.combine(dt.datetime(1,1,1), x,) + dt.timedelta(seconds=df.DRTN_IN_SCND)).time())
```

This works if dt.timedelta(seconds=3) but does not work when I change to dt.timedelta(seconds=df.DRTN_IN_SCND). I get the following error.

```
TypeError: unsupported type for timedelta seconds component: Series
```

Does anyone know how to fix this or of another way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? Thanks!

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? `time_begin` + `DRT_IN_SCND` such at first row would be `16:29:35`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to convert the `DRTN_IN_SCND` and `time_begin` to time deltas if you want to do properly calculations on the columns, pandas has [to_timedelta](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_timedelta.html) which is pretty handy:

```
df['DRTN_IN_SCND'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['DRTN_IN_SCND'], unit='s')
df['time_begin'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_begin'])
df['new_time'] = df['time_begin'] + df['DRTN_IN_SCND']
```

This will give you the new column `new_time`:

```
   time_begin  DRTN_IN_SCND  new_time
0    16:22:16      00:07:19  16:29:35
1    16:29:37      00:00:53  16:30:30
2    16:30:33      00:01:25  16:31:58
```

EDIT:

I'd write this as a chain nowadays.

```
df = (df
    .assign(
        DRTN_IN_SCND = pd.to_timedelta(df['DRTN_IN_SCND']),
        time_begin = pd.to_timedelta(df['time_begin']),
        new_time = lambda df_: pd.to_timedelta(df_.time_begin + df_.DRTN_IN_SCND)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, Hugo. That worked great. I did have to change the format of time_begin from a datetime.time using df.time_begin=df.time_begin.apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%H:%M:%S')), but after that it worked without error.

Comment: `df['time_begin']` can also exist as a **datetime** value too, it doesn't need a conversion to **timedelta**

Comment: @PrageethJayathissa And conceptually it also probably also makes more sense, since it is a point in time and not a length of time.

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

You are using `apply` on `df['new_time']` which is a series and in the `lambda` you are referring to `df.DRTN_IN_SCND` which is another series.  So the error states that you are trying to add a time object to a series object and it doesn't know what to do.

#### Solution

Instead, use `apply` on the dataframe.  In this context, the `x`'s in the lambda function are series and you can access each component via `ix`.  This does what you want.

```
df['new_time'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.ix['time_begin'] + dt.timedelta(seconds=x.ix['DRTN_IN_SCND']), axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, piRSquared. I get the following error when I try your solution. TypeError: ("unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.time' and 'datetime.timedelta'", u'occurred at index 133564'). Do you know what could cause this?

Comment: I don't get that error.  Those types seem completely reasonable to add together to me.  I'll continue to look into it.  If you figure it out, make sure to comment so I know to stop looking.

Comment: Does DRT_IN_SCND need to be formatted in any way? Right now, it's just an int64.

Comment: The error you're getting is correctly identifying the object types `datetime.time` and `datetime.timedelta`.  It's telling us that these are invalid things to add together.  However, this is precisely what we thought we should be adding together.  It works on my machine.  The only thing I can think of is that this is a versioning issue.

Comment: What version do you have? I am using Python 2.7.10 :: Anaconda 2.4.0 (64-bit).

Comment: Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 4.0.0 (64-bit)|

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111249/discussion-between-jess-and-pirsquared).