# i want to add two list having time values in string form in pandas

Tags: string, pandas, list, time, addition

I am making a report of call centre also i want to convert the final time into seconds for further calculation

```
import pandas as pd
df= pd.read_csv('MY_APR.csv')
```

I wanna add new column to my sheet

```
df['Total Talk Time']= pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Inbound Call Talk Time']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Outbound Call Talk Time'])
```

M y inputs are strings: `['02:50:15','05:10:45'.........]` and the output i am getting is in the form `0 days 06:35:49.000000000` after adding the two cells, although time addition is correct I do not require days and the point values after the time.

Comment: You can refer this answer here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37076455/adding-two-time-columns-together-in-pandas-dataframe

Comment: I TRIED THAT BUT i am getting my ans in the form-//0 days 06:35:49.000000000//

Comment: This issue happens when 1 or more of result value are coming greater than 24 hours. You code is working fine on sample value I used with smaller hours.

Comment: please check the data-- here is a google drive link--{ 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1RdpHUddwMZ4ISIrO3BFBRRxGylfT0QWD/view?usp=drivesdk  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try following snippet of code, here I am converting your column `Total Talk Time` to seconds and then parsing to desired time format.

```
df['Total Talk Time']= pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Inbound Call Talk Time']).dt.seconds + pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Outbound Call Talk Time']).dt.seconds
df['Total Talk Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Total Talk Time'],unit='s').dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

This will remove the initial 0 days part in values and keep only time.